# The correct spelling of the space $L^4$

Tags: terminology, lp-spaces, pronunciation

Good morning everybody,

It is well-known that the space of $L^{2}$ function is called: "**the space of square integrable functions**"

What about the space of $L^{4}$ functions? can we say "**the space of fourth-order integrable functions**" ?

All comments and suggestions are welcomed.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think that space has an accepted name. I think "fourth order integrable functions" would not be a good name.since "fourth order" already has another common meaning that's not the one you want.

Comment: @EthanBolker thank you for your comment